# TypeScript: Removing index signature without getting implicitly has an 'any' type error

Tags: typescript

**Details**

I am trying to create a helper function to combine my reducers to have a global reducer to use with react's `useReducer` hook and the context API. I have the functionality of it working but, I am currently not happy with the type checking.

**Problem**

To get it working I had to add `[key: string]: Reducer<any>` in the Reducers type and `[key: string]: any;` in the GlobalState type. If I remove them I get the errors

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type 'GlobalState'.   No index
>   signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
>   'GlobalState'.
>
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type 'Reducers'.   No index signature
>   with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Reducers'.

This leaves me with a `combineReducers` function where I can name the state key anything

**An example**

I have a initial state like this: `{page: {some state}, state2: {some state}}`
and then I combine the reducers like this: `combineReducers({ pages: pageReducer, state3: reducer2 });`

I would now have a state looking like `{page: {some state}, state2: {some state}}, pages: {some state}, state3: {some state}` because of "accidentally" naming the state keys wrong.

**Question**

Is there a way to get this to work when removing `[key: string]: Reducer<any>` in the Reducers type and `[key: string]: any;` in the GlobalState type?

**Code**

types.ts

```js
export type GlobalReducer = (state: GlobalState, action: Action) => GlobalState;
export type Reducer<State> = (state: State, action: Action) => State;

export type Reducers = {
    [key: string]: Reducer<any>;
    page: Reducer<PageState>;
    state2: Reducer<AnotherState>;
};

export type GlobalState = {
    [key: string]: any;
    page: PageState;
    state2: AnotherState;
};

export type PageState = {
    title: string;
    loading: true;
};

export type AnotherState = {
    hello: string;
};
```

combineReducers.ts

```js
import _ from "lodash";

import { Action, Reducers, GlobalState, GlobalReducer } from "./types";

const combineReducers = (reducers: Reducers): GlobalReducer => {
    return (state: GlobalState, action: Action): GlobalState => {
        const reducerKeys = Object.keys(reducers);

        reducerKeys.forEach((key) => {
            const newState = reducers[key](state[key], action);
            state = _.isEqual(newState, state[key]) ? state : { ...state, [key]: newState };
        });

        return state;
    };
};

export { combineReducers };
```

index.ts

```js
export const globalReducer = combineReducers({ page: pageReducer, state2: reducer2 });
```

initialState.ts

```
export const initialState: GlobalState = {
    page: {
        title: "Holidaze",
        loading: true
    },
    state2: {
        hello: ""
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.keys` return an array of string. You have to cast into a array of `keyof Reducers`.

```js
const reducerKeys = Object.keys(reducers) as (keyof Reducers)[];
```

```js
type GlobalState = {
    page: State1,
    anotherPage: AnotherState,
}

type GlobalReducer<State> = (state: State, action: Action) => State;
type Reducer<State> = (state: State, action: Action) => State;

type Reducers<State> = { [K in keyof State]: Reducer<State[K]> }

const combineReducers = <State>(reducers: Reducers<State>): GlobalReducer<State> => {
    return (state: State, action: Action): State => {
        const reducerKeys = Object.keys(reducers) as (keyof State)[];

        reducerKeys.forEach((key) => {
            const newState = reducers[key](state[key], action);
            state = _.isEqual(newState, state[key]) ? state : { ...state, [key]: newState };
        });

        return state;
    };
};
```

Comment: That helps! But I still get an error for the line const newState = reducers[key](state[key], action); 

Argument of type 'PageState | AnotherState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PageState & AnotherState'.

It is state[key] that generates the error

Comment: That fixes it! Thanks :)